# ArcGIS Online Hosted Feature Layer activity log export

Tags: arcgis-online, web-mapping, feature-layer, hosted-feature-layer

Is there a way to export an ArcGIS Online Hosted Feature Layer activity log? The main focus here is to establish who deleted features

Answer (score 0):

The activity log seems to report only at the Item level in your organisations, see this [blog](https://www.esri.com/arcgis-blog/products/arcgis-online/administration/exploring-the-organization-activity-log-csv/).

To actually track who has deleted individual features I think you need to set the [Editing settings](https://doc.arcgis.com/en/arcgis-online/manage-data/manage-hosted-feature-layers.htm#) of the hosted feature layer and enable tracking.

Disclaimer: I've never enabled these options and don't know if this translates into visible actions in the activity log or the information is stored in another table?

Something for you to explore and report back.